# How To Crack The PDF Password?

Tags: passwords, password-cracking, pdf

I need to edit and merge some pdf files which are asking pasword. How can I crack the password?

Comment: Welcome to Information Security Stack Exchange! Unfortunately, this question is off-topic here. Questions asking us to break the security of a specific system for you are off-topic unless they demonstrate an understanding of the concepts involved and clearly identify a specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the legal right to open the encrypted PDF document, you can use a software designed to decrypt the document.

[Advanced PDF Password Recovery Professional edition from ElcomSoft](https://www.elcomsoft.com/apdfpr.html)

The software will use methods like Brute Force, Key Search and Dictionary Attack to guess the password. They will try to use all possible character combinations as the password and so the process might take hours or even days and would really depend on your computer's processing power.

When (if) the password is found, the program shows it, as well as the number of passwords which have been tested, and the program speed.

Legal Issues: - you may be surprised to learn that these PDF password cracking software are absolutely legal and Microsoft even awarded ElcomSoft a Gold Certified Partner status.